# mono Google Calendar Api v2 authentication error

Tags: c#, mono, calendar, raspberry-pi, raspbian

We are busy with an application on a rasp pi where we retrieve a google calendar with the Google Calendar API. We wrote it in C# and tested it on Windows where i works fine. When we compile it on the Rasp PI (xbuild) we don't get any errors, but when we run (mono) it we get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: Execution of request failed: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/USERNAME@gmail.com/private/full?start-min=2013-10-29T14:11:41Z ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Authorization required.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute (Int32 retryCounter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: Execution of request failed: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/USERNAME@gmail.com/private/full?start-min=2013-10-29T14:11:41Z ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Authorization required.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute (Int32 retryCounter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Could someone help us, we don't see a solution.

Comment: It is difficult to know why you get this error, can you provide code? also it might be a problem with the authorization to google API

Comment: our first method did we used to connect, we give as parameters the calendar name, username and password
`public GoogleEventsSyncDataSource(){ service = CalendarHelper.GetService("calender2", "username@gmail.com", "password"); }`

method GetService:
`public static CalendarService GetService(string applicationName, string userName, string password){
            CalendarService service = new CalendarService(applicationName);
            service.(userName, password);
            return service;
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the authentification problem with running the following code:

```
mozroots --import --ask-remove
```

this is because Mono (by default) doesn't allow outside connections, so you have add it to the certificate list.